# macOS keeps crashing during standby

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, catalina, crash

Just bought a brand new Macbook Pro 16 and, unfortunately, it keeps crashing after standby. I have only installed Chrome and Spotify and haven't changed any settings. When I close the lid to put the macbook on standby, macOS seems to crash: when I reopen the lid I keep seeing the system booting up, then my applications reopen with work being lost and an error message displays.

Here is a copy of the errors that I am getting most of the times.

```
panic(cpu 2 caller 0xffffff8014a91b2c): Sleep transition timed out after 180 seconds while notifying clients about upcoming system capability changes. Suspected bundle: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily. Thread 0x74.
Backtracing specified thread
Backtrace (CPU 2), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff83d3433900 : 0xffffff80144471e8 
0xffffff83bec63920 : 0xffffff80143433f1 
0xffffff83bec63990 : 0xffffff8014341c2f 
0xffffff83bec639e0 : 0xffffff80144442e9 
0xffffff83bec63a20 : 0xffffff8014443b4b 
0xffffff83bec63a50 : 0xffffff7f97f99ced 
0xffffff83bec63a80 : 0xffffff7f97fb2f75 
0xffffff83bec63a90 : 0xffffff8014a2ff59 
0xffffff83bec63af0 : 0xffffff7f982be602 
0xffffff83bec63b30 : 0xffffff7f97fa73a6 
0xffffff83bec63bb0 : 0xffffff7f97fa28eb 
0xffffff83bec63c50 : 0xffffff8014a020cf 
0xffffff83bec63cc0 : 0xffffff8014a1a770 
0xffffff83bec63d60 : 0xffffff8014a028b9 
0xffffff83bec63db0 : 0xffffff8014a17e1b 
0xffffff83bec63e50 : 0xffffff8014a14294 
0xffffff83bec63ea0 : 0xffffff8014a11d40 
0xffffff83bec63ef0 : 0xffffff8014a11bd9 
0xffffff83bec63f30 : 0xffffff8014a2d43e 
0xffffff83bec63f70 : 0xffffff8014a2ca36 
0xffffff83bec63fa0 : 0xffffff80142c713e 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(575.1)[D47CA481-C5E5-3F03-9B04-6634DF5F3121]@0xffffff7f97f91000->0xffffff7f97fe1fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[1B1F3BBB-9212-3CF9-94F8-8FEF0D3ACEC4]@0xffffff7f94d11000
         com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl2(5.1.16)[35A245F9-3261-359F-925C-59CDBE8FF584]@0xffffff7f982b3000->0xffffff7f982c7fff
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl(5.1.16)[B2381909-ADF2-3459-AA30-4D8D2DC2AF73]@0xffffff7f982b0000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily(1.4)[9D1FF279-C4A2-3344-902F-E0B22B508689]@0xffffff7f94d08000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[1B1F3BBB-9212-3CF9-94F8-8FEF0D3ACEC4]@0xffffff7f94d11000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(575.1)[D47CA481-C5E5-3F03-9B04-6634DF5F3121]@0xffffff7f97f91000
            dependency: com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl(5.1.16)[56FDE242-D4A6-3E8F-A81C-CE9BA61E3828]@0xffffff7f98001000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task
Boot args: chunklist-security-epoch=0 -chunklist-no-rev2-dev

Mac OS version:
19E287

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 19.4.0: Wed Mar  4 22:28:40 PST 2020; root:xnu-6153.101.6~15/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: AB0AA7EE-3D03-3C21-91AD-5719D79D7AF6
Kernel slide:     0x0000000014000000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8014200000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8014100000
System model name: MacBookPro16,1 (Mac-E1008331FDC96864)
System shutdown begun: NO

System uptime in nanoseconds: 2745236663293
last loaded kext at 647352364593: >usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice   1.2 (addr 0xffffff7f982c8000, size 45056)
last unloaded kext at 1735482350954: >!UAudio   322.2 (addr 0xffffff7f9b694000, size 434176)
loaded kexts:
@filesystems.smbfs  3.4.2
@kext.AMDRadeonX6000    3.0.8
@kext.AMDRadeonServiceManager   3.0.8
>!AGraphicsDevicePolicy 5.1.16
@fileutil   20.036.15
@AGDCPluginDisplayMetrics   5.1.16
>!AHV   1
|IOUserEthernet 1.0.1
|IO!BSerialManager  7.0.4f6
>X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
>!APlatformEnabler  2.7.0d0
>AGPM   111.4.4
>pmtelemetry    1
>!AUpstreamUserClient   3.6.8
@Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X    7.0.0
>AGDCBacklightControl   5.1.16
>!A!IKBLGraphics    14.0.5
>BridgeAudioCommunication   6.70.3
>!AThunderboltIP    3.1.4
>!ATopCaseHIDEventDriver    3430.1
>!AHIDALSService    1
>!A!ICFLGraphicsFramebuffer 14.0.5
>!AAVEBridge    6.1
>!AMuxControl2  5.1.16
>!ABridgeAudio!C    6.70.3
>!AGFXHDA   100.1.426
>!A!IPCHPMC 2.0.1
>!A!ISlowAdaptiveClocking   4.0.0
>!AMCCSControl  1.11
@filesystems.autofs 3.0
>BCMWLANFirmware4355.Hashstore  1
>BCMWLANFirmware4364.Hashstore  1
>BCMWLANFirmware4377.Hashstore  1
>!ABCMWLANBusInterfacePCIe  1
@filesystems.hfs.kext   522.100.5
@BootCache  40
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeDataless    1.0.0d1
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeZlib    1.0.0
>!AVirtIO   1.0
@filesystems.apfs   1412.101.1
@private.KextAudit  1.0
>!ASmartBatteryManager  161.0.0
>!AACPIButtons  6.1
>!ASMBIOS   2.1
>!AACPIEC   6.1
>!AAPIC 1.7
$!AImage4   1
@nke.applicationfirewall    303
$TMSafetyNet    8
@!ASystemPolicy 2.0.0
|EndpointSecurity   1
@kext.AMDRadeonX6100HWLibs  1.0
@kext.AMDRadeonX6000HWServices  3.0.8
|IOAVB!F    840.3
>!ASSE  1.0
@kext.AMDRadeonX6000Framebuffer 3.0.8
@!AGPUWrangler  5.1.16
>!ABacklightExpert  1.1.0
>!AActuatorDriver   3440.1
>!AHS!BDriver   3430.1
>IO!BHIDDriver  7.0.4f6
>!AMultitouchDriver 3440.1
>!AInputDeviceSupport   3440.8
|IO!BHost!CUARTTransport    7.0.4f6
|IO!BHost!CTransport    7.0.4f6
>!A!ILpssUARTv1 3.0.60
>!A!ILpssUARTCommon 3.0.60
>!AOnboardSerial    1.0
>!AHIDKeyboard  209
|IOAccelerator!F2   438.4.5
>X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
>!AGraphicsControl  5.1.16
|IONDRVSupport  575.1
>IOPlatformPlugin!F 6.0.0d8
@kext.AMDSupport    3.0.8
@!AGraphicsDeviceControl    5.1.16
|IOSlowAdaptiveClocking!F   1.0.0
>!ASMBus!C  1.0.18d1
|IOGraphics!F   575.1
@plugin.IOgPTPPlugin    840.3
|IOEthernetAVB!C    1.1.0
@kext.triggers  1.0
>usb.cdc.ncm    5.0.0
>usb.cdc    5.0.0
>usb.networking 5.0.0
>usb.!UHostCompositeDevice  1.2
>!ABCMWLANCore  1.0.0
>mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
>IOImageLoader  1.0.0
|IO80211!FV2    1200.12.2b1
>corecapture    1.0.4
|IOSkywalk!F    1
|IOSurface  269.11
@filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext 1
|IOAudio!F  300.2
@vecLib.kext    1.2.0
|IOSerial!F 11
>usb.!UVHCIBCE  1.2
>usb.!UVHCI 1.2
>usb.!UVHCICommonBCE    1.0
>usb.!UVHCICommon   1.0
>!AEffaceableNOR    1.0
|IOBufferCopy!C 1.1.0
|IOBufferCopyEngine!F   1
|IONVMe!F   2.1.0
>!AThunderboltPCIDownAdapter    2.5.4
>!AThunderboltDPInAdapter   6.2.6
>!AThunderboltDPAdapter!F   6.2.6
>!AHPM  3.4.4
>!A!ILpssI2C!C  3.0.60
>!A!ILpssDmac   3.0.60
>!A!ILpssI2C    3.0.60
|IOUSB!F    900.4.2
>!AThunderboltNHI   5.8.6
|IOThunderbolt!F    7.6.0
>usb.!UXHCIPCI  1.2
>usb.!UXHCI 1.2
>!AEFINVRAM 2.1
>!AEFIRuntime   2.1
>!ASMCRTC   1.0
|IOSMBus!F  1.1
|IOHID!F    2.0.0
$quarantine 4
$sandbox    300.0
@kext.!AMatch   1.0.0d1
>!AKeyStore 2
>!UTDM  489.101.1
|IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice  422.101.1
>!ACredentialManager    1.0
>KernelRelayHost    1
>!ASEPManager   1.0.1
>IOSlaveProcessor   1
>!AFDEKeyStore  28.30
>!AEffaceable!S 1.0
>!AMobileFileIntegrity  1.0.5
@kext.CoreTrust 1
|CoreAnalytics!F    1
|IOTimeSync!F   840.3
|IONetworking!F 3.4
>DiskImages 493.0.0
|IO!B!F 7.0.4f6
|IO!BPacketLogger   7.0.4f6
|IOUSBMass!SDriver  157.101.3
|IOSCSIArchitectureModel!F  422.101.1
|IO!S!F 2.1
|IOUSBHost!F    1.2
>usb.!UCommon   1.0
>!UHostMergeProperties  1.2
>!ABusPower!C   1.0
|IOReport!F 47
>!AACPIPlatform 6.1
>!ASMC  3.1.9
>watchdog   1
|IOPCI!F    2.9
|IOACPI!F   1.4
@kec.pthread    1
@kec.corecrypto 1.0
@kec.Libm   1
```

However, today I've seen this different error message:

```
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff8012a16487): "AppleIntelFramebuffer::setPowerState(0xffffff835ac0a000 : 0xffffff7f95fadd88, 1 -> 0) timed out after 45948 ms"@/AppleInternal/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/xnu/xnu-6153.101.6/iokit/Kernel/IOServicePM.cpp:5296
Backtrace (CPU 0), Frame : Return Address
0xffffffa3f8913b40 : 0xffffff80123215cd 
0xffffffa3f8913b90 : 0xffffff801245a3c5 
0xffffffa3f8913bd0 : 0xffffff801244bf7e 
0xffffffa3f8913c20 : 0xffffff80122c7a40 
0xffffffa3f8913c40 : 0xffffff8012320c97 
0xffffffa3f8913d40 : 0xffffff8012321087 
0xffffffa3f8913d90 : 0xffffff8012ac2c7c 
0xffffffa3f8913e00 : 0xffffff8012a16487 
0xffffffa3f8913e50 : 0xffffff8012a15d69 
0xffffffa3f8913e60 : 0xffffff8012a2d2fe 
0xffffffa3f8913ea0 : 0xffffff8012a14b18 
0xffffffa3f8913ec0 : 0xffffff8012363545 
0xffffffa3f8913f40 : 0xffffff8012363071 
0xffffffa3f8913fa0 : 0xffffff80122c713e 

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task
Boot args: chunklist-security-epoch=0 -chunklist-no-rev2-dev

Mac OS version:
19E287

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 19.4.0: Wed Mar  4 22:28:40 PST 2020; root:xnu-6153.101.6~15/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: AB0AA7EE-3D03-3C21-91AD-5719D79D7AF6
Kernel slide:     0x0000000012000000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8012200000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8012100000
System model name: MacBookPro16,1 (Mac-E1008331FDC96864)
System shutdown begun: NO

System uptime in nanoseconds: 20913263041010
last loaded kext at 17946289441553: >usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.2 (addr 0xffffff7f96342000, size 45056)
last unloaded kext at 17187572337575: >!UAudio  322.2 (addr 0xffffff7f9962d000, size 434176)
loaded kexts:
>!A!BMultitouch 97
@filesystems.smbfs  3.4.2
@kext.AMDRadeonX6000    3.0.8
@kext.AMDRadeonServiceManager   3.0.8
>!AGraphicsDevicePolicy 5.1.16
@fileutil   20.036.15
@AGDCPluginDisplayMetrics   5.1.16
>!AHV   1
|IOUserEthernet 1.0.1
|IO!BSerialManager  7.0.4f6
>AGPM   111.4.4
>X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
>!APlatformEnabler  2.7.0d0
>!AUpstreamUserClient   3.6.8
>pmtelemetry    1
>AGDCBacklightControl   5.1.16
>!A!IKBLGraphics    14.0.5
@Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X    7.0.0
>BridgeAudioCommunication   6.70.3
>!AThunderboltIP    3.1.4
>!ATopCaseHIDEventDriver    3430.1
>!AHIDALSService    1
>!ABridgeAudio!C    6.70.3
>!AGFXHDA   100.1.426
>!AMCCSControl  1.11
>!AAVEBridge    6.1
>!AMuxControl2  5.1.16
>!A!IPCHPMC 2.0.1
>!A!ICFLGraphicsFramebuffer 14.0.5
>!A!ISlowAdaptiveClocking   4.0.0
@filesystems.autofs 3.0
>BCMWLANFirmware4355.Hashstore  1
>BCMWLANFirmware4364.Hashstore  1
>BCMWLANFirmware4377.Hashstore  1
>!ABCMWLANBusInterfacePCIe  1
@filesystems.hfs.kext   522.100.5
@BootCache  40
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeDataless    1.0.0d1
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeZlib    1.0.0
>!AVirtIO   1.0
@filesystems.apfs   1412.101.1
@private.KextAudit  1.0
>!ASmartBatteryManager  161.0.0
>!AACPIButtons  6.1
>!ASMBIOS   2.1
>!AACPIEC   6.1
>!AAPIC 1.7
$!AImage4   1
@nke.applicationfirewall    303
$TMSafetyNet    8
@!ASystemPolicy 2.0.0
|EndpointSecurity   1
>usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.2
>!UAudio    322.2
@kext.AMDRadeonX6100HWLibs  1.0
@kext.AMDRadeonX6000HWServices  3.0.8
|IOAVB!F    840.3
>!ASSE  1.0
@kext.AMDRadeonX6000Framebuffer 3.0.8
>!ABacklightExpert  1.1.0
@!AGPUWrangler  5.1.16
>!AHIDKeyboard  209
>!AHS!BDriver   3430.1
>IO!BHIDDriver  7.0.4f6
>!AActuatorDriver   3440.1
>!AMultitouchDriver 3440.1
>!AInputDeviceSupport   3440.8
@kext.AMDSupport    3.0.8
|IONDRVSupport  575.1
>X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
>!ASMBus!C  1.0.18d1
>!AGraphicsControl  5.1.16
|IO!BHost!CUARTTransport    7.0.4f6
|IO!BHost!CTransport    7.0.4f6
>!A!ILpssUARTv1 3.0.60
>!A!ILpssUARTCommon 3.0.60
>!AOnboardSerial    1.0
>IOPlatformPlugin!F 6.0.0d8
@!AGraphicsDeviceControl    5.1.16
|IOAccelerator!F2   438.4.5
|IOGraphics!F   575.1
|IOSlowAdaptiveClocking!F   1.0.0
@plugin.IOgPTPPlugin    840.3
|IOEthernetAVB!C    1.1.0
@kext.triggers  1.0
>usb.cdc.ncm    5.0.0
>usb.cdc    5.0.0
>usb.networking 5.0.0
>usb.!UHostCompositeDevice  1.2
>!ABCMWLANCore  1.0.0
>mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
>IOImageLoader  1.0.0
|IO80211!FV2    1200.12.2b1
>corecapture    1.0.4
|IOSkywalk!F    1
|IOSurface  269.11
@filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext 1
|IOAudio!F  300.2
@vecLib.kext    1.2.0
|IOSerial!F 11
>usb.!UVHCIBCE  1.2
>usb.!UVHCI 1.2
>usb.!UVHCICommonBCE    1.0
>usb.!UVHCICommon   1.0
>!AEffaceableNOR    1.0
|IOBufferCopy!C 1.1.0
|IOBufferCopyEngine!F   1
|IONVMe!F   2.1.0
>!AThunderboltPCIDownAdapter    2.5.4
>!AThunderboltDPInAdapter   6.2.6
>!AThunderboltDPAdapter!F   6.2.6
>!AHPM  3.4.4
>!A!ILpssI2C!C  3.0.60
>!A!ILpssDmac   3.0.60
>!A!ILpssI2C    3.0.60
>!AThunderboltNHI   5.8.6
|IOThunderbolt!F    7.6.0
>usb.!UXHCIPCI  1.2
>usb.!UXHCI 1.2
|IOUSB!F    900.4.2
>!AEFINVRAM 2.1
>!AEFIRuntime   2.1
>!ASMCRTC   1.0
|IOSMBus!F  1.1
|IOHID!F    2.0.0
$quarantine 4
$sandbox    300.0
@kext.!AMatch   1.0.0d1
>!AKeyStore 2
>!UTDM  489.101.1
|IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice  422.101.1
>!ACredentialManager    1.0
>KernelRelayHost    1
>!ASEPManager   1.0.1
>IOSlaveProcessor   1
>!AFDEKeyStore  28.30
>!AEffaceable!S 1.0
>!AMobileFileIntegrity  1.0.5
@kext.CoreTrust 1
|CoreAnalytics!F    1
|IOTimeSync!F   840.3
|IONetworking!F 3.4
>DiskImages 493.0.0
|IO!B!F 7.0.4f6
|IO!BPacketLogger   7.0.4f6
|IOUSBMass!SDriver  157.101.3
|IOSCSIArchitectureModel!F  422.101.1
|IO!S!F 2.1
|IOUSBHost!F    1.2
>usb.!UCommon   1.0
>!UHostMergeProperties  1.2
>!ABusPower!C   1.0
|IOReport!F 47
>!AACPIPlatform 6.1
>!ASMC  3.1.9
>watchdog   1
|IOPCI!F    2.9
|IOACPI!F   1.4
@kec.pthread    1
@kec.corecrypto 1.0
@kec.Libm   1
```

I've searched elsewhere on the Internet and haven't found a solution. For a similar issue, someone seems to have suggest resetting PRAM/NVRAM. I've tried, but still getting these errors.
The macbook is a 2.4 GHz Intel Core i9 with 32GB memory.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this issue is affecting many others with new MacBooks and that Apple is aware of this issue as reported in this thread https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251274321.

There seem to be a few temporary fixes that can be tried:

- Disable "Prevent computer from sleeping automatically when display is
  off" in Energy Saver settings
- Disable "Enable Power Nap while plugged into a power adapter" in Energy Saver settings
- Unplug the power adapter before sleeping computer
- Shut down the computer instead of putting to sleep

Well, the last one is a no-brainer. The other options are quite unpractical and not good enough for a computer of the value of a MacBook. Hopefully, Apple is working on a proper fix as they are aware of this bug.

In my case, disabling "Enable Power Nap while plugged into a power adapter" in Energy Saver settings seems to have done the trick.

Comment: Update on this: after upgrading to macOS Big Sur and re-enabling Power Nap, the issue no longer seems to happen.